# Cron - schedule job every 30 minutes, starts half past full hour

Tags: cron, schedule

Can I schedule job in cron format so that it runs every 30 minutes from 6:30 am to 11:30, every day? How?

Comment: Yes, but when I set it to `*/30 6-11 * * *` it will start at 6.00, won't it?

Comment: @Przecinek: Yes you are right. It seems that Alvin's answer is better suited...

Answer (score 4):

I think you will need 2 lines to achieve what you need:

```
30 6-11 * * * /path/to/your/command
0 7-11 * * * /path/to/your/command
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alvin's answer I would suggest to insert this line into your crontab:

```
*/30 6-11 * * * /path/to/your/command
```

Comment: OK, Alvin, you got me. It's running at 6 as well.